# Django: get the first object from a filter query or create

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

In Django, queryset provides a method called get_or_create that either returns an objects or creates an object.

However, like the get method, get_or_create can throw an exception if the query returns multiple objects.

Is there an method to do this elegantly:

```
objects = Model.manager.filter(params)
if len(objects) == 0:
   obj = Model.objects.create(params)
else:
   obj = objects[0]
```

Comment: Just add this code as a method on a custom Model manager (or add it to the base manager if you're feeling a little more bold) and call it something descriptive.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[get_or_create()](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py?rev=10929#L318) is just a convenience function  so there's nothing wrong with writing your own, like pavid has shown or

```
result = Model.objects.filter(field__lookup=value)[0]
if not result:
   result = Model.objects.create(...)
return result
```

**EDIT**
As suggested, changed the [:1] slice (which returns a single-entry list) after the filter to [0] (which returns the actual object). The problem with this is it will raise an exception if there is not match to the query.

This will also raise a simliar exception:

```
Model.objects.filter(field_lookup=value).latest()
```

Looking at the question again, I'm not sure whether the original poster is looking to return multiple objects/rows, or just a way to get around raising an exception when retrieving a single object/row.

Here's another option?

```
results = Model.objects.filter(...)
if results.exists():
    return results
else:
    return Model.objects.create(...)
```

and another:

```
result = None
try:
    result = Model.objects.get(...)
except Model.DoesNotExist:
    result = Model.objects.create(...)
```

There's nothing wrong with raising & catching exceptions!

Comment: and which solution is the more efficient? Do you have any idea?

Comment: sometimes python makes things easier than you expect. this helped me with a somewhat unrelated problem: In my current project. I (stupidly) have an extra get call to the db just to throw a DNE error because even though I wanted a filter result, I didn't know how to check for an empty queryset (it was on my to-do list to research). If not. Too simple! hahah

Comment: As written, this returns either a one-element list or an object. Probably ought to add ``if result: result = result[0]``

Comment: -1 because [0] throws an exception, which is not mentioned in answer

Comment: -1 because [0] throws an exception, which is not mentioned in answer

Answer (score 38):

From django 1.6 there is a convenience method first() that returns the first result in a filter query, or None.

```
obj = Model.manager.filter(params).first()
if obj is None:
    obj = Model.objects.create(params)
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a manager method that will allow you to extend this function elegantly

```
class FilterOrCreateManager(models.Manager):
"""Adds filter_or_create method to objects
"""
def filter_or_create(self, **kwargs):
  try:
    created = False
    obj = self.filter(**kwargs).first()
    if obj is None:
      obj = self.create(**kwargs)
      created = True
    return (obj,created)
  except Exception as e:        
    print(e)
```

Then ensure you add the manager to whichever model(s) you want to use this on:

```
class MyObj(models.Model):
  objects = FilterOrCreateManager()
```

After that, you will be able to use it as you would `get_or_create`:

```
obj_instance, created = MyObj.filter_or_create(somearg='some value')
```

Comment: This is the best answer out here, should have been the accepted answer in my opinion.

Comment: Why swallow the exception?

Answer (score 7):

I just came across this question and wanted to contribute because no one has suggested actually catching the IndexError.

```py
try:
    obj = Model.objects.filter(params)[0]
except IndexError:
    obj = Model.objects.create(params)
```

Answer (score 5):

Do it in one line:

```
obj = Model.objects.filter(params).first() or Model.objects.create(params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
result = Model.objects.filter(field__lookup=value)[0]
if not result:
   result = Model.objects.create(...)
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

In your view, call something like this:

```
obj = Category.objects.get_or_create_category(form.cleaned_data.get('name'))
```

In your Model manager, create a function like this:

```
class CategoryManager(models.Manager):

    def get_or_create_category(self, query):
        try:
            result = Category.objects.filter(name = query)[0]
        except:
            result = Category.objects.create(name = query)
        return result
```

The logic is simple. First, try to retrieve the first Category object who's name matches the query string (which is provided by the form). If the retrieval fails (because it doesn't exist), create a new Category with the string as its name. Return the result for use in your view.